# Connecting to GeoServer from Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gis, geoserver

I've built an OpenGeo Suite simple editor app using this tutorial: http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/webapps/ol3/templates.html#creating-an-editor-application.

To see it, I have to run `suite-sdk debug -g http://localhost:8080/geoserver /path/to/myapp` to connect to geoserver.

I want to move the map with layers to my Rails app, but have no idea how to connect to `geoserver` from there.

Comment: Search for WMS on here and gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Once you have geoserver, you connect to it using a Javascript Web-Mapping Library. The easiest one to get started with is [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html). From there on in it's fairly standard web development. If you want click interactivity, there's a few way to do it, but there's a really good one using ajax, so let me know if you want to do that.